# <cfcookie ...> Causing Error Only on Local

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The code I'm working with has the following lines in the `OnSessionStart` function in `Application.cfc`:

```
<cfcookie name="CFID" value="#SESSION.CFID#" />
<cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#SESSION.CFTOKEN#" />
```

On my LocalHost, these lines trigger an error ("Element CFID is undefined in SESSION") the first time I try to load the app. But then when I refresh, it loads normally.

On the deployed environments (DEV and PROD), it works fine, without an error.

I've looked through the code, and determined that these cookies are never read explicitly by the code, so I commented them out in my LocalHost. This eliminated the error on my LocalHost -- but when I deployed the change to DEV it prevented the LDAP authentication from completing (even though it had completed successfully on LocalHost). Therefore, I had to reverse the change.

Which brings us to the question: **How can I eliminate the error in my LocalHost without compromising the login process in DEV and PROD?** (Certainly I can live with the error if I must -- but a consistent code base that works identically and reliably in both places is much more desirable.)

I'm very comfortable debugging the code -- but I suspect this issue has something to do with the configuration, and I don't really know where to start beyond the simple experiments I've done above.

Points that may be useful to others with more knowledge and experience than I have:

- The LocalHost computer is Windows (Windows 7).
- The DEV and PROD environments are on Linux.
- LocalHost, DEV, and PROD all use the same login process: `<cfldap>`.
- We updated at the end of 2014 from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11 in all environments (including my LocalHost). This issue did not present itself in ColdFusion 9; rather, it started when I updated to ColdFusion 11.
- I do not have access to the ColdFusion Administrator on the Linux machines (DEV and PROD), although I do, of course, have access to it on my LocalHost.

Comment: Are you using J2EE session variables?

Comment: I was using J2EE session variables on my LocalHost -- but I'm told that they were not used on DEV and PROD. I turned them off on LocalHost and the problem disappeared. @Leigh, it looks like you're not hurting for points -- but if you want to put this as an answer, I'll upvote it and mark it correct.

Comment: Also, this raises an issue of whether we *should* be using J2EE session variables in all environments. If you have any observations I should take to our server administrator, I'll do so.

Comment: Appreciate the offer, but you should write it up as an answer :) Generally [J2EE is considered more secure than the default](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/predictable-cookie-session-ids-reported.html). I do not have time to find the article I am thinking of, but If you do a search, it should turn up a lot of discussions on J2EE vs CF session identifiers, differences, etcetera.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html

Comment: @JoeDeRose - Do not forget to write up an answer to close out this thread :)

Comment: Well, it was really *your* insight that led to the answer. But I wrote it up. If you decide you want the points, just post an answer and I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider enabling/disabling J2EE session variables in ColdFusion Administrator: **Server Settings > Memory Variables > Use J2EE session variables**.

(In the situation for which I posed the question, the problem was resolved by *dis*abling J2EE session variables.)